# k8s - Pod restart time

Tags: kubernetes

I was running this to see how job restart works in k8s.

```
kubectl run alpine --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure -- exit 1
```

The alpine image was already there. The first failure happened almost within a second. k8s takes 5 minutes to do 5 restarts! why does it not try immediately? Is there any way reduce the time between 2 restarts?

[image]

Comment: How does your pod config look like?

Comment: what do you mean by that? the image is alpine and command would be 'exit 1' . everything else is default.

Comment: what does the `kubectl describe pod <your_pod name>` return?

Comment: Perhaps, you couldn’t even do that because it never starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) docs:

> Exited Containers that are restarted by the kubelet are restarted with an **exponential back-off delay** (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped at five minutes, and is reset after ten minutes of successful execution.

I think that there is no way to configure the back-off delay time.
*EDIT: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57291) requesting this feature.*

Also, note that using `kubectl run` **you are not simulating "job restarts"**. Jobs are managed by [Job Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures), which behaves a little bit different when handling pod/containers errors, as it takes into account the combination of `restartPolicy`, `parallelism`, `completions` and the `backoffLimit` configs:

> There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of
>   retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set
>   .spec.backoffLimit to specify the number of retries before considering
>   a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6. Failed
>   Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with
>   an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped at six minutes.